# Maven war build put old version of some jar files in generated .war file

Tags: maven, build, war

I'm trying to build a (war) project with maven, but when I see the generated war file It consists some older jar files which are not exists in pom.xml file and are the older version of some other jar files.I deleted the .m2 folder but the problem is exists yet.
I'm novice in maven, any idea?

Comment: Try `mvn clean package` if you have older version of your dependencies in target folder, these will be removed ab won't be packaged

Comment: :( Unfortunately It doesn't work!

Comment: You need to be more specific. There is a flag to check latest artifact versions ` -U,--update-snapshots ` and some artifacts can be resolved from transitive dependencies, then you need to define correct version explicity in pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Those old jars are probably [transitive dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies). If you are using Eclipse you can figure out using the Dependency Graph feature of m2e, else you could try the [maven-graph-plugin](http://mvnplugins.fusesource.org/maven/1.4/maven-graph-plugin/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `mvn package` uses the jars from the ~/.m2/repository if they are present. And the copying (installation) is only done when you do `mvn install`.